# Remove areas of steep increase in a raster

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator

I have DEM that is misaligned vertically. This misalignment is not uniform and changes across the raster. I want to correct it by comparing it to a more accurate DEM.

My methodology would be.

1. Create Difference Raster
2. Remove values >2m and below <2m (removed areas that have changed significantly between LiDAR acquisition)
3. Interpolate no-data values caused by step 2
4. Create points across raster at a set interval
5. Create Grid across raster
6. For each grid, find the average point height per grid to get the correction value for that location
7. Use correction raster to fix vertical allignment

The problem Is that there are areas of steep change caused by things like buildings. These areas will distort the mean values for step 6 and I would like to remove them from my difference raster.

The image below is the difference raster highlighting these anomolies where there is a steep increase.

[image]

I am looking for a way to automatically remove these anomalies and replace the values by interpolating from nearby cells. I am using QGIS but am open to using other open-source software.

Comment: Have you tried Slope - Raster calculator slopes > some value = 0 else 1 - Warp to set 0 as nodata - Fill no data

Comment: I used a raster calculator with slopes, as you suggested, and then used the Gaussian filter from the Saga toolbox and that did a pretty good job